# Median of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Given a sorted, doubly linked list, how would you go about finding the median element? The one way I can think of is to traverse the list once and once a value repeats, We know we've traversed the whole linked list. At his point, we know how many elements there are, so we can go the median since it's already sorted, which would be:

running time: O(n)
space complexity O(n) as well.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You are talking about Mode or Median?

Comment: The median is just the middle value right? What does it have to do with any repeats? The more efficient way is to use a vector and not a list.

Comment: I'm talking about the median. It's sorted, but it's given as a linked list, so I don't initially know how many elements there are.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, depending on multiple things, like whether you have a tail pointer like any good double-linked list would have.  If you do, it should be obvious. If you don't, use two pointers and double hop one while single hopping another. The latter is for the median-find. There will be  edge cases of whether a double hop lands on the last node (even number of nodes) or one-off the last (odd number of nodes). Flesh those with with some paper, a pencil, and some boxes and arrows. It will make sense.

Comment: Well, if you are really talking about the Median, then what has the repeated value to do anything with it?

Comment: @WhozCraig, thank you, that makes sense after drawing it out

Comment: You tagged C++, so use `mylist.size()` to get the size of the list.

Comment: The problem statement about a doubly linked linked list doesn't make much sense unless there's a tail pointer to the last node in the list. Assuming there is a tail pointer, you follow the list inwards starting with pointers at both ends,  until both pointers point to the same node. You'll need to check for equal pointers at the start and each time you update either pointer.

Comment: go to node n/2,where n is size. that's the median. So O(n). Size should be known, since finding the size should be a side-effect of sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1.Have 2 pointers p1 and p2 to the start of the link list
2. Store the value of the start node in some temp variable
3. for every 2 nodes that p2 advances, p1 should advance 1 node .Continue this
   until p2->next is the repeated node
4. In this way when this loop  ends p2 will be at the last node and p1 will be at       the median node.

Comment: Im guessing  user3708902 has confused doubly link list with circular link list

Comment: Running time is O(n) again. I don't think, there is an more efficient algorithm. is there ??

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using 2 pointers p1 and p2.

Initially the 2 pointers will be pointing to the head of the List.

Now, traverse the List where, p1 advances 2 times and p1 advances once until p2 reaches the end of the List.

When p1 has traversed the complete List, p2 would have traversed half of the List, thus pointing to the "Mid" of the List.